# How To See Who Has Liked A Picture In Php And My Sql Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on a image posting site where we can see and like the pictures.

When we like a picture, we add one more to total likes, but when we login next time how can the webpage know if the current user has liked the picture or not?

I am using a MySQL database to store the name of the image and the number of likes.

I have a button. When the user clicks it, it adds one more like.

So any suggestion for the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's an helping website. Post your code, tell us what's not working, we'll help. If you want somebody to write your code, call a web agendy.

Comment: Before to post a question on SO you should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by storing user likes pro picture in a separate table. The table should contain two columns - picture_id and user_id. Well, I assume, that you have a picture_id in your pictures table and that you also have a table with users, which has user_id. If not - do so.
As soon as user likes a picture, you store this relation in the table and can retrieve it afterwards. Hope, this helps.

Comment: SORRY THAT Didnt Help I Can Make Separate Table For Each Picture

Comment: I Cant Make A Table For Each Picture

Comment: Can I Store User Id Who Has Liked The Picture In The Same Table

Comment: I have table with colums            1) Postid A random number 2) postimage   name of the image uploaded  3)description of the picture 4) likes which contains number of likes. Can i add another column to store usernames who have liked it             if so please tell me how to do so        and  how to retrieve it and use the usenames

Comment: As i said, you can't come out with just one table. You should have at least 3 tables or even 4 tables, if one post can contain several pictures. First table - posts (post_id, text). Second table - pictures (picture_id, post_id, picture_name, total_likes). Third table - users (user_id, user_name). Forth table - likes (picture_id, user_id). Note, that you don't need a separate table for _each_ picture. All the information can be stored and retrieved with the database schema, which I proposed.